# Anonymous type error with Union with joins in LINQ

Tags: linq

I am trying to perform a union on multiple tables to produce a total number of gallons of fuel.  Some tables have only one column for gallons of fuel, while other tables have two or three. I am in Visual Studio 2013 LINQing to the data in SQL Server 2012 with .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 6.

Visual Studio 2013 gives me the error that `'Anonymous Type # 1' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and no extension method 'Union' accepting a first argument of type 'Anonymous Type # 1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` I have looked at other articles about anonymous types and am still unclear as to the best way to modify the code. The error Visual Studio is pointing out is in the `var fueltable` line containing the keyword Union, near the bottom.The data type for all "gallons" columns is decimal, so I am unsure about what data type to change. Should I put Union somewhere else, or change the type, or something different entirely?  Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
  public IHttpActionResult FuelTax(FuelTaxBindingModel fuelinfo)

  {

    ...

    var trucks = Array.ConvertAll<Trucks ,string>
                (fuelinfo.selectedTrucks,
                 x=>x.FT_Tractor.ToString() ).ToArray();

    var temptable1 = (from t1 in db.FuelTaxDetails 
                           join t2 in db.FuelTaxes 
                             on t1.FTD_FT_Key equals t2.FT_Key
                           join t3 in db.OtherFuelTransactions
                             on t2.FT_API_Apl_Key equals t3.api_key
                      where (t2.FT_API_Apl_Key == fuelinfo.apikey)
                             && (t2.FT_LoadDate >= fuelinfo.beginningDate 
                             && t2.FT_LoadDate <= fuelinfo.endDate)
                             && (trucks.Contains(t2.FT_Tractor))
                      select new { t1.FTD_State, t1.FTD_Miles, t1.FTD_NonToll,
                                        t1.FTD_Toll, t3.Gallons };

    var temptable2 = (from a in db.FuelTaxDetails
                          join b in db.FuelTaxes
                            on a.FTD_FT_Key equals b.FT_Key
                          join t4 in db.ComdataTranslations
                            on b.FT_API_Apl_Key equals t4.API_Key
                          join t5 in db.ComdataTransactions
                            on t4.Comdata_Key equals t5.CDNCompanyCode
                      let Gallons = t5.NumberofTractorGallons 
                                     + t5.NumberofReeferGallons
                                     + t5.OtherFuelGallons
                      where (b.FT_API_Apl_Key == fuelinfo.apikey)
                             && (b.FT_LoadDate >= fuelinfo.beginningDate 
                             && b.FT_LoadDate <= fuelinfo.endDate)
                             && (trucks.Contains(b.FT_Tractor))
                      select new { a.FTD_State, a.FTD_Miles, 
                                   a.FTD_NonToll, a.FTD_Toll,
                                   Gallons });

    ... 

    var fueltable = temptable1.Union(temptable2)
                    .OrderBy(s => s.FTD_State)
                    .GroupBy(s => new { s.FTD_State })
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                     FTD_State = g.Key.FTD_State,
                     FTD_Miles = g.Sum(x => x.FTD_Miles),
                     FTD_NonToll = g.Sum(x => x.FTD_NonToll),
                     FTD_Toll = g.Sum(x => x.FTD_Toll),
                     Gallons = g.Sum(x => x.Gallons)
                    });
```

Comment: You're using `SingleOrDefault` on all of your `temptable` variables - so you're getting single values, not sequences. That means you can't use a `Union` of them. Additionally, please take more time to format the code in your question (it's all shifted over to the right) and ideally reduce your code to a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - currently there's a *lot* of almost-certainly-irrelevant code in there, and it's still not complete enough for us to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: OK, thank you.  When I delete SingleOrDefault, I still get the "does not contain a definition for 'Union'" error, and I also get the error, "Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>'.

Comment: Do you have a using statement for `System.Linq`?

Comment: Yes, I do have the using statement.

Comment: (Just to correct myself, I meant a using *directive* rather than statement, but hey...) Looking at your two queries now, they use different anonymous types - they've got different propertes (e.g. `gallons2` vs `Gallons`). You can only create a union of sequences of the same type. (Or a unions between a sequence of a supertype and a sequence of a subtype, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: I'm still getting the same two errors even if I change any variation of *gallons*, e.g. *gallons2*, to just *gallons*.

Comment: `Gallons` is still different to `gallons` - you've got to make sure that your two sequences are of the *same* anonymous type.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected that, but it's still giving me the same two errors I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Which error, exactly? (And again, if you could make this a short but *complete* example, it would help.)

Comment: OK, thank you for your patience. On closer examination, one error was actually different from what I posted before--both errors are at the **var fueltable** line.  One is **'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Anonyous#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union<TSource> (System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments.**

Comment: Other error is **Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<AnonymousType#2>.'**

Comment: It sounds like there are still two anonymous types involved then... if the property *names* still match, check the property *types*. Hover over the declaration of each of the individual bits and it should show you more details.